# Identify cells containing specific strings and overwrite content with numbers using Python

Tags: python, pandas, replace, substitution

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

[image]

My goal is to identify for each cell of every column if the following strings are contained: `'KSS'`, `'ABC'`, `'DEF'`, `'ABC / DEF'`, `'KSS / DEF'`

Subsequently I would like to substitute the content with the following values: `'KSS'` -> 100, `'ABC'` -> 200, `'DEF'` -> 300, `'ABC / DEF'` -> 400, `'KSS / DEF'` -> 500

The output should be like something like this:

[image]

Notice: the algorithm should be generic and check every column, not only number 3. For sake of completeness the data types are all `objects`.

So far my line of codes are these but I guess they are incomplete...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np  
df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['XYZ', 'BALSO', 'PISCO', 'KSS', 'Yes', 660, 'Cop'],
        ['XYZ', 'TONTO', 'LOLLO', '195', 500, 'Yes', 'nan'],
        ['XYZ', 'CALLO', 'WANDA', 'ABC / DEF', 'Yes', 500, 'nan'],
        ['XYZ', 'AZUNGO', 'FINGI', 'KSS / DEF', 'Yes', 500, 'nan']
    ])
df = pd.read_csv('prova.csv', sep=',', skiprows=0, header=None, low_memory=False)
df.str.replace('KSS|ABC|DEF','?')
```

Comment: Here we go again with nonsense downvoting....

Comment: because there is no code to write... I load everything from a .csv file! The question is clear for everybody and the images help to make it understandable... if you don't like it's fine, it's not my problem but I see some good people out there who are more concerned about the problem rather then complaining about two images...

Comment: I think what ayhan is saying is that you've not posted raw data to reproduce your df, if you'd posted text for the data we could load that from the clipboard and help you but by posting images, you immediately placed a barrier for the community to help you. You should consider our viewpoint, if you'd seen this question how would go about trying to reproduce it? Anyway, if you define a dict or series with your lookup values then you can just do `df['3'].map(your_dict)` but you'd need to filter out rows where there is no match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a dict with your lookup and replacement values then you can call [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas.Series.map) on this column, additionally you need to pass `na_action='ignore'` to `map` otherwise you get a `KeyError` for the missing values, additionally you will note that as you have missing values the values get converted to `float` but you can cast again using `astype(int)` later:

```
In [182]:
d={'KSS':100, 'ABC' :200, 'DEF' : 300, 'ABC / DEF' : 400, 'KSS / DEF' : 500}
df[3] = df[3].map(d, na_action='ignore')
df

Out[182]:
     0       1      2      3    4    5
0  XYZ   BALSO  PISCO 100.00  660  Cop
1  XYZ   TONTO  LOLLO    nan  500  nan
2  XYZ   CALLO  WANDA 400.00  500  nan
3  XYZ  AZUNGO  FINGI 500.00  500  nan
```

here we cast the type using `astype`:

```
In [178]:
df[3] = df[3].astype(int)
df

Out[178]:
     0       1      2    3    4    5
0  XYZ   BALSO  PISCO  100  660  Cop
1  XYZ   TONTO  LOLLO  195  500  nan
2  XYZ   CALLO  WANDA  400  500  nan
3  XYZ  AZUNGO  FINGI  500  500  nan
```

Comment: Can just use `.isin(d)` instead of calling its `.keys()` method there...

Comment: @JonClements actually it's unncessary as `map` takes a `na_action` param so if you pass `na_action='ignore'` then it won't bork and raise `KeyError`

Comment: Haha... was just going to mention that - beat me to it :)